# MYSQL large LIMIT offset

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

i have searched for a solution for this, but alas, nothind.

Currently my table is pushing 5 800 000 rows, from 5000 different sources. E.G:

```
CREATE TABLE stores(
  store_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE articles(
  article_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
  article_name CHAR(80),
  article_price INT UNSIGNED,
  store_id INT UNSIGNED
);
```

Ok, so i have made indexes like so:

```
CREATE INDEX article ON articles(store_id,name);
```

And i thought i made it bulletproof, guess not.

When i search large datasets, 200 000 articles, im issuing:

```
  SELECT article_name,
         article_price 
    FROM articles 
   WHERE store_id = $id 
ORDER BY article_name 
   LIMIT 100000,20;
```

And getting very large reply times. Help please? :S

Answer (score 1):

Yes, well i figured it out, as no one else will help me :D

The idea is as follows, when i reguest some page i do the following:

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result(row_id,article_id);
SET @row:=0;
INSERT INTO result SELECT @row:=(@row+1),article_id FROM articles ORDER BY $sort $order;

and then a simple SELECT/JOIN:

SELECT * FROM result 
LEFT JOIN articles ON result.article_id = articles.article_id
WHERE row_id >= $from AND row_id < $to;

Cheers...

Comment: Is it still working for you from performance overview? Can you provide more details about your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried two separate indices on store_id and article_name?  This may allow for more efficient filtering and ordering by MySQL.  You could also consider moving this query into a stored procedure so that MySQL has the ability to cache the execution / sub-result-sets. If none of that works, you may want to consider the number of insert/update/delete operations that are occuring on that table.  If they are high, you could consider replication to a slave db where all read operations occur.  If none of that works, you may want to upgrade your hardware as MySQL should be able to handle tables of this size quite easily.

Comment: Basicly, this table is bomarded all day. 24/7 i have inserts and updates. I have a global index on article_name, not on store_id. I dont think that a separate index on id would do anything. I use myisam table, is that a good idea cause it uses table lock, is that messing with my performance? I repeat, the table is constantly updated and has many many inserts per day.

EDIT: i have slow query enabled, and this is what i get

# Query_time: 7  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 24  Rows_examined: 8224

Btw, the box is VPS with xeon e5520, but i have only 2 cpu cores and 3GB of RAM.